# Multiples for loops

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to populate cell(0) datagridview with the following valus

```
8:00
8:10
8:20
8:30
8:40
8:50
.
.
21:50
```

so I write this code ,but in my 6 rows I have the same value =8:50 from the first row to the last row

```
Dim i As Integer 'Counter 1
        Dim ii As Integer 'Counter 2
        ' make 1st loop for hours
        For j = 0 To 71
            For i = 8 To 20
                ' mkae 2nd loop for minutes
                For ii = 0 To 50 Step 10

                    DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = (i & ":" & ii)
                Next


                    DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = (i & ":" & ii)


            Next

        Next
```

Comment: I would expect to see 9:50 (not 8:50) in each row. You are setting Rows(0).Cells(0) to each time in turn, ending with 9:50. Then you set Rows(1).Cells(0) to each time in turn, ending with 9:50, and so on up to Rows(5).

Comment: The behavior of the code you posted is easy to understand. The only variable that changes in the left-hand side of the assignment is `j`, and so of course you will get only six rows, each with the same value (i.e. the last value assigned through each of the inner loops). But it's not actually clear what you really want. Do you want just six rows, `8:00` to `8:50`? Do you want twelve rows `8:00` to `9:50`? Do you want 72 rows, with six copies of `8:00` to `9:50`? Something else? Please improve your question.

Comment: yes ,I adapte my code just for explain better my problem , the problem I have the some value in all rows 9:50 and me I want time 8:00 to 9:50

Comment: in cell(0) of my datagrid ,is dedicated to time ,it start to 8:00 and end at 21:50 , so I want populate my datagrid cell(0) by these values

Comment: As far as I can tell, you should have only one loop.  You should start with a base value - probably a `TimeSpan` representing `8:00:00` - and then loop through the rows of the grid and display that value.  After displaying the current value, you add 10 minutes to it.  You can do more than one thing in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is continually updating the same cell from 8:00 until it reaches 8:50.

**UPDATED BASED ON YOUR COMMENT**

You had the inner and outer loops reversed...
I think what you want is:

```vb
     Dim RowCount as int = 0
     For i = 8 To 21
         For j = 0 To 5
             ' mkae 2nd loop for minutes
             DataGridView1.Rows(RowCount).Cells(0).Value = (i & ":" & (J*10))
             RowCount += 1
         Next    
    Next
```

Note that I didn't test this, but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: in cell(0) of my datagrid ,is dedicated to time ,it start to 8:00 and end at 21:50 , so I want populate my datagrid cell(0) by these values

Comment: Sorry, as I noted, I didn't test it (left it up to you). I edited the code to add a row counter back. Not very elegant, but I think it works.

Comment: Thank you daShier you save my life

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have something like this:

```
Dim time = TimeSpan.FromHours(8)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    row.Cells(0).Value = time.ToString("h\:mm")
    time += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
Next
```

That assumes that the correct number of rows are already in place, which appears to be the case based on what you posted.

Comment: thank you but an error appear la conversion de la chaîne "hh:mm" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.

Comment: and if I want to stop to 21:50 how to do this ?